# replace a word using regex wont work

Tags: python, regex

Post text is a list of tweets. I want to replace url adresses in every tweet with "URL". But when i print "post_text", i see nothing is changed, although when i print "tweet" i see that it has been replaced. How can replace url adresses in post_text???

```
for tweet in post_text:
    tweet=re.sub(r'http\S*', "URL", tweet)
```

Comment: You never assign the computed `tweet` back to your list, hence the regex substitution never "sticks."  See the answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is happening as your `tweet` variable is a new variable which is never assigned back to the list.

Try using a list comprehension instead:

```
post_text = [re.sub(r'http\S*', "URL", tweet) for tweet in post_text]
```

Or you can use `enumerate` to use the item index during the loop. This is recommended if you have a more complicated loop than what is in the question:

```
for i, tweet in enumerate(post_text):
    post_text[i] = re.sub(r'http\S*', "URL", tweet)
```

Comment: Thank u so much! It's working. SInce i am new in python, may i ask you why i need to put [:] after post_text, i haven't seen that yet? Everything else is clear.

Comment: It's not necessary in this case. I've removed it to simplify the answer

Comment: @cvizrada, don't forget to mark the answer as a solution if this worked for you :)

Comment: Oh, i am new here, so i did't see that option before. I marked it, it was helpful, thank you very much. :)